# linkedlist add and remove not working as expected, Java

Tags: java, iterator

The following code is a Queue which is supposed to add and remove integer values but the function are not working as intended. Only first two values are added and remove function shows null pointer exception. 
In addition, the iterator class is not iterating over the Integer values. It causes infinite loop. What is the cause?

Thank you.

Comment: There is a big flaw in your design: you can't remove an element from the end without knowing the previous element, you are using `back = back.next` which does the opposite and breaks the structure. You need to store both next and back in each node or traverse it each time.

Comment: Is there any reason that you're not using [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)? It's available in JRE6 and up

Answer (score 1):

These two lines in the `add` method seem to be creating a cycle:

```
front.next = previousNode;
previousNode.next = front;
```

The cycle here results in the infinite loop in iteration.

I think what you need is just to set the next of the previous node to the new node.

```
previousNode.next = front;
```

Also this part of the `remove` method doesn't seem correct:

```
E n = back.element;
back = back.next;
if (back == null)
    front = null;
else
    back.next = null;
```

The problem here is that you're setting `back.next` to null every time, which makes you lose the rest of the queue.

In order to fix that you just need to remove the else part, so that you keep the old next.

```
E n = back.element;
back = back.next;
if (back == null)
    front = null;
```